GKE nginx service responds with 201 created then for some reason ingress responds with 502 error
This issue is global and also reproduced from time to time on uat. The root cause is that A SERVICE makes a request to B and request goes through ingress which is based on nginx. B-ingress redirects request to ms-xxx-service but when B-service responds with 201 created then for some reason ingress responds with 502 error
Environment details : Google kubernetes Engine , Nginx Controller , POds
[DEBUG] 2024-07-01 03:26:45.355 DEBUG [transaction.id=26fcc267d65692a6, trace.id=51dfa4cb5af2cc7adbebaaa258c81f77, user.code=,logcompany.code=, customer.number=\] 1 --- \[or-http-epoll-2\] c.t.e.observability.logging.HttpLogger   :

Server Response Headers:
HTTP/1.1 502 Bad Gateway
traceparent: 00-51dfa4cb5af2cc7adbebaaa258c81f77-26fcc267d65692a6-01
Date: Mon, 01 Jul 2024 03:26:45 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 552
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=15724800; includeSubDomains
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: DENY
X-XSS-Protection: 0
Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'none'
Referrer-Policy: no-referrer

Body:
   502 Bad Gateway
   
   <h1>502 Bad Gateway</h1>
   <hr>nginx`
   
   
   <!-- a padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page -->
  <!-- a padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page -->

Our API is not working as expected

The details for "201 Created":

can you please help understand what the root cause is?
